# Finding stalks of the two point topological space

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory

> Let $X$ be the two element set $\{0, 1\}$, and make $X$
> into a topological space by taking each of the four subsets to be open. A
> sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ is thus a collection of four sets with certain maps between them. Find the stalks $\mathscr{F}_0$ and $\mathscr{F}_0$.

To find $\mathscr{F}_0 = \varinjlim_{0 \in U} \mathscr{F}(U)$ we see that only $\{0\}$ and $X$ contain $0$.

So we have and indexing category $I$ with two objects $X$ and $\{0\}$ and morphism $$\{0\} \hookrightarrow X.$$ Now  $\mathscr{F}$ is a contravariant functor so we get $$\mathscr{F}(X) \to \mathscr{F}(\{ 0 \})$$ in the category of whatever $\mathscr{F}(U)$'s belong to. Now I think that we want to make the diagram $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \mathscr{F}(X) @>\alpha>> \mathscr{F}(\{0\})\\ @.     {_{\rlap{\ \beta\circ \alpha}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VV\beta V\\  @. \mathscr{F}_0 \end{CD}$$ commute and also satisfy the universal property that the direct limit requires. Is there a way to explicitly compute $\mathscr{F}_0$ using this?

Comment: It is just $\mathscr{F}(0)$.

Comment: The lesson here is that if your diagram that you are taking a colimit over has a final object, then the colimit is just the value at the final object. In this case, a final object is a smallest open subset containing a point, which in the case of the discrete topology is *just that point*.

Comment: It might also be worthwhile to show that there is an equivalence of categories of $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$ and $\mathbf{Set}^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take $\mathscr{F}_0=\mathscr{F}(\{0\})$ and $\beta=1_{\mathscr{F}(\{0\})}$.

Then a cocone of the diagram consists of a pair of maps:\begin{eqnarray*}
u\colon \mathscr{F}(\{0\})&\to& A\\
v\colon \mathscr{F}(X) &\to& A
\end{eqnarray*}
with $v=u\alpha $.

Our induced map $\mathscr{F}_0\to A$ is then just $u$.  As $\beta=1_{\mathscr{F}(\{0\})}$, we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}u\beta\alpha=u\alpha=v\\
\\
{\rm and}
\\
\\u\beta=u.\end{eqnarray*}

Conversely $u$ is the only map $w\colon \mathscr{F}(\{0\})\to A$ such that $w\beta=u$.  Thus the universal property is satisfied.