# Top. space with $3$ points and sheaves $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ such that a morphism is surjective on stalks, but the map on sections is not.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am working on a problem where I'm being asked to find a topological space $X$ that consists of $3$ points, sheaves $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ such that a morphism $\varphi$ between $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ is surjective on stalks i.e the map $\varphi_x$ is surjective, but the map on sections $\varphi(U) : \mathscr{F}(U) \to \mathscr{G}(U)$ is not surjective.

Of the top of my head I knew that $X = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}/60 \mathbb{Z}$ consists of $3$ points namely $X = \{(2), (3), (5)\}$ and given the Zariski topology would be a topological space with $3$ points. Now I would need to figure out how to construct $\mathscr{F}$, $\mathscr{G}$ and $\varphi$ such that the map on stalks is surjective, but the map on sections is not. Is there some general way to think about this construction? In a sense I need to find some open set $U$ for which $\mathscr{G}(U)$ contains points that $\mathscr{F}(U)$ doesn't have a preimage. In the case with $X$ the open sets are $$\emptyset,  \{(2)\}, \{(3)\}, \{(5)\}, \{(2), (3)\}, \{(2), (5)\}, \{(3), (5)\}, X$$ if I didn't miss any. Any hints on how to construct suitable sheafs for this?

Comment: Your space $X$ is discrete. You can't have such an example on a discrete space. There is a counter-example on the three-point space with one open point and two closed points.

Comment: What's the issue with the discreteness here, it's not immediate to me at least why for any sheaves there couldn't be an section of $\mathscr{G}(U)$ with no preimage in $\mathscr{F}(U)$? @Thorgott

Comment: On a discrete space, $\mathcal{F}(U)=\prod_{u\in U}\mathcal{F}_u$. So you couldn't use a discrete space to solve this problem.

Comment: Excuse me my ignorance, but I still don't see why $\mathcal{F}(U)=\prod_{u\in U}\mathcal{F}_u$ is a problem here? @KReiser

Comment: Well, a product of surjective maps of sets (or abelian groups, or...) is surjective, so if your map of sheaves is surjective on stalks, and the sections are the products of the stalks at the points in the open, then your map is surjective on sections, isn't it?

Comment: That makes it clear, thanks. Now I just have to figure out why $\mathcal{F}(U)=\prod_{u\in U}\mathcal{F}_u$ for a discrete space as this wasn't covered in Eisenbud & Harris. Is this a simple proof or will it take some work? @KReiser

Comment: You can do this directly from the definition of a sheaf and the results of your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678197/finding-stalks-of-the-two-point-topological-space).

Comment: It's a straightforward consequence of applying the sheaf condition with the cover $\{ \{ x \} \mid x \in U \}$ of $U$.  (But that said, you're not going to need to prove this in your answer - the comment is just a guide to steer you away from trying to find examples on discrete spaces, since that approach is going to end up failing.)

Comment: And a further comment: I don't think there's any point in looking for examples coming from algebraic/arithmetic geometry, as $3$-point spaces can all be described quite explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I could possibly consider $X = \{a,b,c\}$ and take some simple topology for it, but right now my issue is probably not having a solid intuition of sheaves as I cannot really come up with many possible candidates in order to break this surjectivity.

Comment: As a suggestion, you can take the $\mathcal{G}$ to be the terminal sheaf, given by $\mathcal{G}(U)=\{\ast\}$ for all open $U$. The stalks of this sheaf are then also singletons, so you get a counterexample if you manage to find a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ all of whose stalks are non-empty, but which has no global sections.